# android.support.v7.app.actionBar all method throw null pointer exception

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have an `ActionBarActivity` in `TabActivity`. when I call `getSupportActionBar()`'s  methods like `setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS)` and so on, the `ActionBarActivity` will throw NPE.

I spent a lot of time to search the stackoverflow but not work.

1. My style is `Theme.AppCompat.Light`
2. I did not hide the actionBar
3. The actionBar is not null (I have debug it).
4. all above works perfect on android 2.3 but 4.3.

The codes:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_news);

    bar = getSupportActionBar();
    (line 38)bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    bar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.news_pager);
    urlGenerator = new UrlGenerator("getNewsClasses");
    pagerAdapter = new NewsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
         @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                bar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
    });
}
```

The error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarImplICS.setNavigationMode(ActionBarImplICS.java:229)
at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarImplJB.setNavigationMode(ActionBarImplJB.java:20)
at com.ccw.estate.news.NewsActivity.onCreate(NewsActivity.java:38)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
... 24 more
```

The menifest:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
 <activity
        android:name="name"
        android:label="label" >
  </activity>
</application>
```

The AppTheme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

Who knows how it. thanks!

Comment: What is line 229 in `ActionBarImplICS.java`?

Comment: Post the manifest file also

Comment: You are using this `Activity` as a tab in a `TabActivity`(if yes you shouldn't do this)?

Comment: @Raghunandan I search it on google but not found. it is android source code.

Comment: @Luksprog This is my MainActivity `Intent i = new Intent().setClass(this, Activity.class);
  TabSpec tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("name").setIndicator("name").setContent(i);`

Comment: @jame `bar` is null. If you apply a non action bar theme to the activity then you get this.

Comment: @Raghunandan I test `bar == null` return `false`.

Comment: Rethink your approach. Apparently using an `ActionBarActivity` as a tab in `TabActivity` doesn't properly initialize the `ActionBar`. And what you are trying to do will not make any sense at all, it will be counter intuitive for the user and against any Android design principles. Also, `TabActivity` is deprecated, use fragments for what you currently try to do.

Answer (score 3):

Did you add the property (android:windowNoTitle) of ActionBarActivity?
Adding "android:windowNoTitle" means no action bar is created. Therefore getSupportActionBar() will return null.